# Recover domain after loss of access to host?

Tags: domains, web-hosting

So I'm in a familiar situation.   I work for a small company who had a string of web agencies develop a wordpress site for them.  I am a hardcore dev and we are trying to bring the website back in house.

This particular site is hosted by google sites.

However...no one knows anything about the account used to access the back end, and we are not paying the bill for hosting.  Our current design agencies, and all of the ones I've contacted all claim to also not know the account associated with the google sites login, and claim their not paying the bill either.  They all claim to only have access to the wordpress CRM.

Google will not help me out without account or billing information?

So the question is:
   How do force google to shutdown hosting my site so I can build another host?

I've ran into this sort of thing before, but I've always been able to find that one piece of info that becomes turnkey for me.  In this case, it looks like I will never be able to get access to the host ever again....

Comment: Why do you need to shut down the hosting?   Just pointing the domain to different hosting will work whether or not the old hosting is still running.

Comment: Good question... I guess I could probably copy the current site from the wordpress, CRM.  I'm looking into this solution now.